# How can I make a PHP 'foreach' loop repeat entire line?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

My objective is to allow users to select from check boxes and when they click submit it combines all PDFs into 1 PDF. (each check box has a PDF value).

```
<?php 
include 'PDFMerger.php';
$pdf = new PDFMerger;


$pdf1 = "/path/pdf1.pdf";
$pdf2 = "/path/pdf2.pdf";
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?php echo $pdf1 ?>"><label>PDF ONE</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?php echo $pdf2 ?>"><label>PDF TWO</label><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>


<?php

if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){

    $pdf->addPDF($selected);
}
}
?>
<?php
ob_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$pdf->merge('download', 'TEST223.pdf');

}
?>
```

I am not a PHP expert at all, so I am sure there are many errors in the above code.  But the problem lies with the 'foreach" area I think. It only repeats the $selected part.. not the entire line for each PDF.

So, if users select only 1 box.. it works fine. If they select more than one it puts the pdf path one after the other in the code and the Merger program can't use that.

```
//To visualize the issue.. I need the loop to produce this:
$pdf->addPDF("/path/pdf1.pdf");
$pdf->addPDF("/path/pdf2.pdf");
$pdf->addPDF("/path/pdf3.pdf");
etc...

//It is currently producing:
$pdf->addPDF("/path/pdf1.pdf/path/pdf2.pdf/path/pdf3.pdf");
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: The foreach loop is doing what you want. It looks like the problem is in your PDFMerger class.

Comment: @shaunl thank you for the response. The PDFMerger class is in a separate document. Can you give me an idea of what to look for? How could I determine where the issue is?

Comment: Try commenting out your `merge()` function and turn the items in the foreach to echoed variables to check

Comment: Are you saying that $selected contains all selected strings concatenated one after the other?

Comment: @georaldc yes exactly.. I did do what nomistic mentioned and you see below the results in the second code box.. it comes out just one after the other. I need the $pdf->addPDF(""); to repeat as well.. the entire line, not just the $selected portion.

Comment: Inspect $_POST['check_list']. It should be an array with all values checked. Doesn't make sense for it to be an array with only a single element when multiple entries have been checked

Comment: Does `$selected` contain an array on POST? It should be as @geroaldc says. This would mean the `addPDF()` method on the other class could be the culprit.